# How to make a WordPress CPT act like a custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

Alright, I have two custom post types. Team & Locations.

I need Locations to act as a taxonomy for Team members, however Locations also has its own set of information. I would like locations to be directly tied to the team member locations taxonomy, so as new locations are added, the locations are available when adding new team members.

Comment: So you need common taxonomy for both post type am i getting you right?

Comment: Not quite, I need the Locations post type to also act as a taxonomy for teams, I assume i need a custom locations taxonomy, but i don't know how to make the options within it related to the locations pt.

Comment: Why are you using a CPT for locations instead of adding the required meta fields to the taxonomy?

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand the question, but I still need to query the locations list and data separately from the team at certain times.

Comment: You can still query the taxonomy independent of the CPT. So just make locations the taxonomy to Team.

Answer (score 0):

We have this:

**CPT 1**: Team
**CPT 2**: Locations

and suppose you want a custom taxonomy (*call it Address -- less confusing*) that is tied to both Team and Locations CPT:

**Custom Taxonomy**: Address

What you can do is when you register your custom taxonomy (*assuming you did that, and are not using Posts categories*), you do the following to tie 'address' custom taxonomy to both Team and Locations CPT:

```
[...]
register_taxonomy( 'address', array( 'team', 'locations' ), $args );
[...]
```